# How to redirect a URL without a query string to a URL with a query string?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, redirect

I've looked around for the answer to my question but only to be confused even more. I'm hoping somebody can help me...

I need to redirect this URL:

```
http://www.testsite.co.uk/ecommerce/cabinets/aluminium_cabinets
```

To:

```
http://www.testsite.co.uk/products/cabinets/?types[]=illuminated-aluminium-cabinets&types[]=non-illuminated-aluminium-cabinets
```

Please help :)

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: You just want to redirect that one static URL, or any URL that follows a specific pattern? What are the criteria? Where does the parameter data come from?

Comment: Just that one yes. There others similar but once I know how to do this one, I should be able to workout the format for the otherts. The destination URL parameters are created when  selecting two filters. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 RedirectMatch ^/ecommerce/cabinets/aluminium_cabinets/?$ http://www.testsite.co.uk/products/cabinets/?types[]=illuminated-aluminium-cabinets&types[]=non-illuminated-aluminium-cabinets
```